# Cancel/abort a connection from the ThreadSafeClientConnManager connection pool

Tags: java, android, thread-safety, connection-pooling, httpclient

I'm using [ThreadSafeClientConnManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.html) to manage a *pool of client connections*, because my application has several threads, which are simultaneously connecting to a webserver.

Abstract sample code:

```
HttpClient httpClient;
ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(parameters,schReg);
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, parameters);
```

Now lets say on of this threads is downloading a large file, but then the user of my application is switching to another activity/screen. Therefor the file is needless and I'd like to abort this download connection.

In [ThreadSafeClientConnManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/conn/tsccm/ThreadSafeClientConnManager.html) I found this method:

`public ClientConnectionRequest requestConnection (HttpRoute route, Object state)`
Returns a new ClientConnectionRequest, from which a ManagedClientConnection can be obtained or the **request can be aborted**.

So far I've been using:

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URL_TO_FILE);
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
[...]
```

Now from what I understand, I've to use:

`httpclient.getConnectionManager().requestConnection(HttpRoute route, Object state);`

And that's the point where I'm stuck. I assume that for the route I can just use `new HttpRoute(new HttpHost("10.0.0.1"))` or whatever my server is, but what to put in for `Object state`?

And second, as soon as I've the `ClientConnectionManager` I can call `getConnection(long timeout, TimeUnit tunit)`. But then from there, how I do I execute my `HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URL_TO_FILE);` as I did before with `HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);`?

I've been gone through the documentation and tried out quite a few different things, but I wasn't able to obtain a working solution. Therefor any suggestions and/or code examples are more than welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to call `httpRequest.abort()` and the connection should be closed.

With a large file, you must have a loop process the data. You can just check the cancel status and abort from there,

```
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        while (instream.read(buf) >= 0) {
            if (cancelled)
               httpRequest.abort();
            // Process the file
        }
     }
```

When pooling or keepalive is used, the aborted connection can't be returned to the pool and it must be closed. There was a bug in older versions that the connection is kept alive and it messes up next request. I think this is all fixed.

Comment: Thanks. That's way easier than what I tried to do ;-) The connection doesn't show up in netstat any more after the abort(). I assume that it is closed then.